# Access the self signed certificate details

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, ssl, self-signed

I have an asp.net mvc website deployed to iis. A self signed SSL certificate is used in order to secure the traffic. I would like to access this self signed certificate from my asp.net, probably in the `startup` class or something, in order to get the validity of the self signed certificate (i need this metric for something else).

How could i do that?

I would gladly post some code, or what I've tried so far, but sadly i have no clue where to start from!

I would really appreciate any help.

**Edit**

To rephrase my question, lets say i have an asp.net web service deployed to IIS, how do i access the certificates in that IIS, and retrieve their validity period (from with in the web service using c# code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by opening the cert store and finding certs based upon search criteria. If it's a self signed cert that you created you should know something about it.

```
object value = "AcmeOrganization";
X509FindType findType = X509FindType.FindByIssuerName;
StoreName storeName = StoreName.My;
StoreLocation storeLocation = StoreLocation.CurrentUser;
var store = new X509Store(storeName, storeLocation);
try
{
  store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
  var certs = store.Certificates.Find(findType, value, true);
  if (certs.Count > 0) 
  {
    return certs[0];
  }
}
finally
{
  store.Close();
  store = null;
}
```

This will get you the cert you're looking for then you can call Verify which does chain validation. Other properties along with expiration will be available with the X509Certificate2 object.

```
certs[0].Verify()
```

Comment: Damn, this looks indeed like what i am looking for (y), an upvote for now, and another upvote + accepted answer, after i succesfully try that }:)